# deviceready is not called in Samsung S2 GT I9100

Tags: android, android-webview, cordova-3

I've installed my app on Samsung S2 GT I9100, but its not working.
The problem I figured out is, deviceready of cordova is not been called.

I read some articles, many people faced this problem. But no solution worked for me.

I tried the same app on other devices also it worked (like Moto, Samsung other devices, Asus etc).

Comment: Have you checked the version of android installed in your device (on which the app is not working).

Comment: Nope.@RaghavendraShivhare

Comment: It's working on 4.4 and 5.1, I've checked tested on these 2 versions. But 4.0.3 it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Cordova doesn't support android versions which goes below 5% distribution according to [Cordova-Platform-Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/index.html). So you need atleast 4.1+ to continue to use Cordova in your app. Other wise you can switch back to older version of Cordova.

You can see latest survey of [Google's distribution dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for quick response.